# Eclipse plugins - separate Editor and icons assignment

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have defined standard TextEditor to open *.git* files. ([code at GitHub](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/org.nodeclipse.gitaddon))

```
   <!-- git -->
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.editors">
      <editor
            class="org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextEditor"
            contributorClass="org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.BasicTextEditorActionContributor"
            default="true"
            extensions="gitignore,gitmodules,gitattributes"
            icon="icons/git.ico"
            id="org.eclipse.ui.DefaultTextEditor"
            name="Text Editor">
      </editor>
   </extension>
```

However this code changes icon for TextEditor, whatever file I open.

Is the only way the custom Text Editor? **Are there particular extention points only for file types?**

UPDATE: Defining own Editor as below

```
import org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextEditor;

public class GitFilesEditor extends TextEditor{
```

make matter even more complicated (I don't like idea to specify all those items)

```
Multiple markers at this line
- The type org.eclipse.jface.text.source.Annotation cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
- The type org.eclipse.jface.text.revisions.RevisionInformation cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from     required .class files
- The type org.eclipse.jface.text.source.ISourceViewer cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
- The type org.eclipse.jface.text.IRegion cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
- The type org.eclipse.jface.text.source.IVerticalRuler cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

Comment: Do you mean that the icon of the editor is different depending on the the specific file type? Note that only gif and png images are supported - not ico images.

Comment: Icons are set for Editor, not file type. So the only way is to define Editor with new ID but possibly old class (as Bananeweizen said).
.ico files also worked, but with uncontrollable size selection. For example Editor choose 64x64 icon, which made Eclipse touch ready :) Fall back to .png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your editor has the same ID like the default text editor:

```
id="org.eclipse.ui.DefaultTextEditor"
```

That surely confuses the Eclipse editor extension lookup. Just use a self defined ID there, like

```
id="org.nodeclipse.editor.git"
```

And I would also change the name to "Git Text Editor" or something like that to avoid duplicate labels in the editor preference page.

Comment: My intention was to use standard Editor. But the code about redefine icon for it. So the question is "Is defining MyEditor class the only way?" Can I extend file types? I have found only
org.eclipse.team.core.fileTypes  
http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_team_core_fileTypes.html

Comment: Why don't you at least _try_ what I write? You want to invoke the same editor _class_. That does not mean that you need the same ID. So therefore please change the one line I mentioned. You don't need to implement an own class.

Comment: I got it. This id is like instance id, while the class is the same.